# Creating server-side GUI (Qt) on every client-connect: unresponsive GUI

Tags: c++, qt, client-server, boost-asio

I want to create a C++ multi-client server (`asio`) application that creates a server-side Qt GUI instance for every established connection to a client. The GUI will be associated with the connection.

Problem: The created GUI instances remain unresponsive. Removing a recursive call (shown below) in the `asio::async_accept` handler solves that, but obviously doesn't allow another client to connect.

The design is based on [OneLoneCoder's Networking tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hNdkYInj4g&t=1275s&ab_channel=javidx9)

The MWE does not include error handling, resource management etc...

**MWE**

Header file `communication.h`:

```
#ifndef COMMUNICATION_H
#define COMMUNICATION_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "dep/3rdparty/asio/asio.hpp"

#include <QMainWindow>


// Provides read/write methods and message handling (removed for brevity).
// Associated with a Server/Client's asio::io_context, owning an individual socket.
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Connection> Unique;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Connection> Shared;

    explicit Connection(asio::io_context& context, asio::ip::tcp::socket&& socket);

    void connect(const std::string& remoteIp, const uint16_t remotePort);

    // contains methods for synchronous/asynchronous read/write,
    // but omitted for brevity.

private:
    asio::io_context& mContext;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket mSocket;
};


class Client : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Client> {
public:
    void connect(const std::string& serverIp, const uint16_t serverPort);

    void loop();

private:
    asio::io_context mContext;
    Connection::Unique mConnection;
};


class TestWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestWindow(Connection& connectionRef, QWidget* parent) : mConnectionRef(connectionRef), QMainWindow(parent) {}

private:
    Connection& mConnectionRef;  // Used to interact with the client.
};


// Resembles a session that consists of a connection to a client, a GUI (and other things hidden for brevity). Used by the server to keep track of all associated GUIs and to communicate with them (e.g. close all, ...).
class Session {
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Session> Unique;
    Session(Connection::Unique&& connection);

private:
    Connection::Unique mConnection;
    TestWindow* mTestWindow = nullptr;
    void setupAndShowGui();
};


class Server {
public:
    static const std::string localhost;
    explicit Server(std::string ip, uint16_t port);

    bool start();

private:
    asio::io_context mContext;
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;

    void waitForConnections();
    std::vector<Session::Unique> mSessions;
};


#endif //SAMPLEEDITOR_COMMUNICATION_H
```

Implementation file `communication.cpp`

```
#include "communication.h"


Connection::Connection(asio::io_context& context, asio::ip::tcp::socket&& socket) : mContext(context), mSocket(std::move(socket)) {}

void Connection::connect(const std::string& remoteIp, const uint16_t remotePort) {
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints = asio::ip::tcp::resolver(mContext).resolve(remoteIp, std::to_string(remotePort));
    asio::async_connect(mSocket, endpoints, [this](std::error_code ec, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Connection error.\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Connected to " << mSocket.remote_endpoint() << "\n";
    });
}

void Client::connect(const std::string& serverIp, const uint16_t serverPort) {
    mConnection = std::make_unique<Connection>( Connection(mContext, asio::ip::tcp::socket(mContext)) );
    mConnection->connect(serverIp, serverPort);
    mContext.run();
}

void Client::loop() {
    for (;;) {
        // client would read/write messages and react
    }
}


Session::Session(Connection::Unique&& connection) : mConnection(std::move(connection)) {
    setupAndShowGui();
}

void Session::setupAndShowGui() {
    if (mTestWindow == nullptr) {
        mTestWindow = new TestWindow(*mConnection, nullptr);
        mTestWindow->show();
        std::cout << "Test Window created, associated with connection at address " << &mConnection << ".\n";
    }
}


const std::string Server::localhost = "127.0.0.1";

Server::Server(std::string ip, uint16_t port)
: mAcceptor(mContext, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::make_address_v4(ip), port))
{
    asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
    mAcceptor.set_option(option);
}

bool Server::start() {
    std::cout << "Starting server (" << mAcceptor.local_endpoint() << ").\n";
    waitForConnections();
    mContext.run();
    return true;
}

void Server::waitForConnections() {
    auto acceptHandler = [this](std::error_code ec, asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) {
        if (ec) {
            throw std::system_error(ec);
        }
        asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
        socket.set_option(option);
        std::cout << "Received connection request from " << socket.remote_endpoint() << ".\n";
        Connection::Unique newConnection = std::make_unique<Connection>( Connection(mContext, std::move(socket)) );
        Session::Unique session = std::make_unique<Session>(Session(std::move(newConnection)));
        mSessions.push_back(std::move(session));
        waitForConnections();  // <--!-- remove this line and GUI becomes responsive
    };
    std::cout << "Waiting for connections...\n";
    mAcceptor.async_accept(acceptHandler);
}
```

Client application:

```
#include "communication.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Client client;
    client.connect(Server::localhost, 60000);
    client.loop();
    return 0;
}
```

Server application:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "communication.h"

class ServerGui : public QApplication {
public:
    ServerGui(int argc, char **argv) : QApplication(argc, argv), mServer(Server(Server::localhost, 60000)) {
        mServer.start();
    }

private:
    Server mServer;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ServerGui gui(argc, argv);
    gui.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is also a `CMakeLists.txt` file to build.
We assume `CMakeLists.txt` and all source files to be in `src/` and all `asio` files in `src/dep/3rdparty/asio/`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(mwe)

set(DEBUGGING_FLAGS false)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

if(${DEBUGGING_FLAGS})
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /Od /Zi")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Od /Zi")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /DEBUG")
endif()


set(DEP_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep")
set(QT_BASE_PATH "C:/Qt/6.3.2/msvc2019_64")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${QT_BASE_PATH}/lib/cmake/")
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Concurrent)


set(HEADERS
    communication.h
)

set(SOURCES
    communication.cpp
)

set(FORMS
)

set(RESOURCES
)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${QT_BASE_PATH}/include/
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_Server
    main_server.cpp
    ${HEADERS}
    ${SOURCES}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_Server PRIVATE
        Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Concurrent
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_Server PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_MockClient
        main_mock_client.cpp
        ${HEADERS}
        ${SOURCES}
        )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_MockClient PRIVATE
        Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Concurrent
        )
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_MockClient PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Why do you want a GUI on the server side? That seems really odd.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This will run on localhost and allow GUI-based communication with a connected client.

Comment: The problem is that `gui.exec` (which starts the Qt event loop) isn't executed, due to `asio::io_context::run` (which blocks the thread) being executed inside the `ServerGui` constructor.

Comment: Not sure what the best solution is, but using different threads for Qt and asio may be a solution.

Comment: @m7913d I had one approach with a thread that does the listening, but then I couldn't create GUI elements (because I was in another thread). The solution must be something that listens for a new connections in a new thread, but moves the new connection/socket object into the parent thread (where the "business logic" then works with the socket)...

Comment: ***but then I couldn't create GUI elements (because I was in another thread)*** Keep the GUI in the main thread and use signals and slots to communicate between the background thread and the GUI.  That is what I do in my applications at work that use Qt socket communications.

Comment: @drescherjm Yep, this and/or the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` function... Do you see a solution in which the TCP part can remain non-Qt? Also, is it a problem that the `context` object of the Server is actually passed by reference to all created connections?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `Server::start`:

```
waitForConnections();
mContext.run();
```

`mContext.run()` blocks. This means nothing else executes. The simplest "quick fix" is to replace `io_context` with a `asio::thread_pool`, but it may not work well with Qt's assumptions on threading.

Instead you'd want to integrate the event loops of the io context with Qt's. See e.g. [How to integrate Boost.Asio main loop in GUI framework like Qt4 or GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001032/how-to-integrate-boost-asio-main-loop-in-gui-framework-like-qt4-or-gtk)

I've previously done a quick-and-dirty appraoch of the same for a Gkt GUI: [How to communicate with child process asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646956/how-to-communicate-with-child-process-asynchronously/71656002#71656002)

I recommend using a ready-made implementation.